Romantic Comedy Film About a Part-time Porn Actor/School Teacher
I remembered watching a comedy drama movie years ago. The only thing I remember is that the lead actress was a school teacher (may be kindergarten) who is also a part-time porn actress (I think) and uses a spec and nerdy appearance when going to school as a teacher. She meets a guy/don't remember whether he was a parent of a student or someone recently migrated to the city. I have some shoddy memories of some scenes (comedy) related to the porn industry and some Indian origin guy/guys. Don't have any other clear idea about the film. 
It's a romantic comedy drama film. I think the approximate release year might be between 2000 and 2010. The movie was in English. Not sure whether it was a Hollywood movie or Indy movie.

Was it the movie - The Guru (2002)?

Heather Graham (Sharonna) is a porn star who is engaged to a firefighter who thinks she is a School Teacher.
Jimi Mistry (Ramu Gupta) is a guy who's moved to the US from India. 

That's it. Thank you. Will get the movie and watch it. :)
